# How to change line comment format in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use default toggle comment line (editor.action.commentLine) to add/remove line comment (PHP).

My comments look like

```
// $someVar = null;
```

I want to change comment line format from `//` to `// ~`. Is there any way to change the default line comment format?

Comment: As a result of my research, I strongly have the opinion that you are not able to do this. But you can suggest to team developer to add this feature https://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks, Masoud. Your links seems to be pointing to Visual Studio IDE. But I speak of Visual Studio Code. But this doesn't change the main idea of your comment. Alas, it seems, you are right. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an extension, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax), to do this.  Demo:

[image: php lineComment demo]

The setting is as simple as :

```
  "custom-language-properties": {
    "php.comments.lineComment": "// ~"
 }
```

Modifying `blockComments` and `brackets` (as well as `lineComments`) are supported for many languages - with the ability for the user to add additional language support pretty easily.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share the extension link? :-)

Comment: LOL, I forgot that - edited the answer to include it.  Thanks.